# not able to send real time data into aws personalize

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-personalize

I created an api endpoint to send my user interaction data into the personalize recommendation engine in real time. However, when I tried to send the post request to this endpoint I get an error saying `AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:iam::21847893275720:user/demo-user is not authorized to perform: personalize:PutEvents because no identity-based policy allows the personalize:PutEvents action`

How do I solve this issue? Do I need to add additional parameters in the putEventsParams?

my api function looks something like this

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';  

var personalizeevents = new AWS.PersonalizeEvents({
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION});

const streamInteractions = async (req, res) => {
    const { eventType, userId, trackingId } = req.body;
        var eventDate = new Date();
        var putEventsParams= {
            'sessionId': '1', 
            'trackingId': trackingId,
            'userId': userId,
            eventList: [
                {
                  'eventType': eventType, 
                  'sentAt': eventDate
                },
            ]
        }
        personalizeevents.putEvents(putEventsParams, function (err, data) {
          if (err) {
                console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
          }
          else{     
                console.log(data);           // successful response
          }
        });
    res.json('Done!');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message indicates, your user requires the `personalize:PutEvents` action to be able to call the `putEvents` API. Add a policy such as the following to your user in IAM.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "personalize:PutEvents",
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thanks, it doesn't show the error message anymore. Now just shows `{}` in the console after i send some data so I think that means it's successful. Is it possible to see the data that I've send in personalize through the putEvents api? Also, are you the James Jory from the deep dive series?

Comment: The PutEvents API does not provide a response; just an HTTP status code where 200 indicates success. To see the ingested data, you can [export the interactions dataset](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/export-data.html) (`ingestionMode` `PUT`). There are also CW metrics for [PutEvents requests and errors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/cloudwatch-metrics.html). And, yes, I am the James from the video series. ;-)